# Google Analytics Social Tracking Facebook Referrer

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, referrer

I understand that Google Analytic's Advanced Segments can be used to track referrals made from Facebook. I am creating my own tracking system and want to emulate this referral tracking feature. I assume as google analytics is javascript based, it would use the 'document.referrer' to achieve this. However, the document.referrer is not tracked from https based connections, a.k.a facebook. so my question is:

How Google Analytics track traffic generated from Facebook? How can I emulate this using a javascript?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, IE blocks referrer when user moves http to https.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/178066/en-us?fr=1

So if you host your tracking code on https protocol, maybe it works.

Comment: maybe, but that means forced HTTPS for hosting, I don't think Google Analytics has that limitation

Comment: I did test on IE and document.referrer was 'http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=...'. It was 'https://www.facebook.com' on chrome. Maybe was Facebook detect IE and use non-https landing page? if that was, why your code doesn't work? maybe need more research :(